# Need help on Deep learning model on sentiment analysis

Tags: deep-learning

Before I present my problem, please note that I am a newbie in deep learning and I am trying things for the first time. Most of my code/logic were adopted from various references in the internet.

Goal : Build a LSTM/CNN model to classify the IMDB reviews available in tensorflow datasets

Approach 1 : 1) LSTM based - train data - 45000 (10% validation split),test data - 5000 , accuracy > 95% , validation_accuracy > 85% , glove embeddings of size 100 was used
Approach 2 : 1) CNN model - a) train data - 45000 , test_data - 5000
b) train data - 50% , test_data - 50%
accuracy > 95% , validation_accuracy > 85%

Code :  https://github.com/shankartmv/Deep-Learning-Work/blob/main/IMDB_Sentiment_reviews_using_tensorflow_dataset.ipynb

Problem : Test_data accuracy doesn't go beyond 52% with both the approaches.Most of the code/references available out there use test_data during training.  test_data wasn't part of my training.

Methodologies tried to increase test accuracy :

1. Movie reviews length (padded) and max number of words in the vocabulary
2. dropout
3. epochs
4. train test split ratio
5. embeddings trainable=true/false
6. with and without GLove word embeddings

My guess is there isn't enough training data. I need help on how to increase the test data accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Most of the code/references available out there use test_data during training. test_data wasn't part of my training.*

While this is the way we should do it but stuff like Encoding must be done holistically.

 In your case, you have called the `pre_process` separately for Test and Train.

 *So, the words are converted to Numbers independently. This should not happen*.

`tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test)`

Above Tokenizer should be the one that was fit on train data.

If I randomly print token with key 101 for train, test. This is the result

```
print(train_tokn.index_word[101])
print(test_tokn.index_word[101])
```

> think
>
> characters

I think you should use the train_tokn for the test data and it should improve. *I believe a very simple LSTM can achieve 85% on this dataset*

Or, manually embed both Train, Test using the GloVe embedding.

**A simple example for the issue**

```py
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

train = ['I am sorry'] 
test = ['I am very sorry']
max_words = 10 

# Train
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train)
tokenizer.index_word # {1: 'i', 2: 'am', 3: 'sorry'}
# Test
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(test)
tokenizer.index_word  # {1: 'i', 2: 'am', 3: 'very', 4: 'sorry'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped !! I am able to improve my test accuracy.

Comment: Please mark the Answer as Accepted. Thanks!!!